# very basic system of equations by Cramer's method

Tags: systems-of-equations

Consider the system of linear equations:
$$
\begin{align*}
2x + 3y &= 5 \\
4x - y &= 2
\end{align*}
$$

I'm trying to find the solutions for x and y. If anyone could provide insights or a step-by-step solution, I would greatly appreciate it.

I need to solve it by Cramer's method, I have used Gaussian elimination and I have made graphs and the solution must be x=0.79, y=1.14

EDIT: my attempt
$$
\Delta = \begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 4 & -1 \end{vmatrix} = (2 \cdot -1) - (4 \cdot 3) = -14
$$

For $ \Delta_x $ and $ \Delta_y $, I substituted the constants:

$$
\Delta_x = \begin{vmatrix} 5 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 \end{vmatrix} = (5 \cdot -1) - (2 \cdot 3) = -11
$$

$$
\Delta_y = \begin{vmatrix} 2 & 5 \\ 4 & 2 \end{vmatrix} = (2 \cdot 2) - (4 \cdot 5) = -18
$$

Now

$$
x = \frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta} = \frac{-11}{-14} \quad \text{(correct)}
$$

$$
y = \frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta} = \frac{-18}{-14} \quad \text{(incorrect)}
$$

Comment: Do you know how to set up Cramer's Rule? If there is confusion, you should share that try.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I have edited the post with my procedure

Answer (score 2):

$$
\Delta_y = \begin{vmatrix} 2 & 5 \\ 4 & 2 \end{vmatrix} = (2 \cdot 2) - (4 \cdot 5) =4-20= -16
$$
Then,

$y=16/14=1.14$ approximately

Comment: ohh Thanks!!!..